# can x / (1/y) be expressed more simply

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If you divide an number by another numbers reciprocal

i.e

x / (1 / y)

Can this be expressed in another way

is dividing by the reciprocal equivelant to another operation?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{y}} = xy$.

This is a simple consequence of two things: $x = \frac{x}{1}$, and
$$\frac{\quad\frac{a}{b}\quad}{\frac{x}{y}} = \frac {ay}{bx}.$$
The latter is just the usual rule for [dividing fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Division), written in fraction form.

Answer (score 8):

The only possible issue with writing $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{y}}$ as $xy$ is that you lose the information that $y\ne0$.  So if you are thinking about them as functions then they aren't quite the same.  But whenever $y\ne 0$, $\frac{x}{\frac{1}{y}}=xy$ as noted in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** $\ $ "Integralize" the denominator, i.e. multiply by $\rm\ y\ $ the denominator (and numerator).
This is analogous to "rationalizing" a denominator $\rm\:b\:$ by multiplying by its conjugate $\rm\:b'\:$, i.e. $$\rm\displaystyle \frac{a}{b} = \frac{a\:b'}n,\ \ n = b\:b'\in\mathbb Q\:.$$